# Configure CMake to add_library base on current Android build type

Tags: android, cmake, java-native-interface, native

I store my credential keys inside a `cpp` native file and use CMake to build then link it to my app:

**Current code:**

My `src/main/cpp/credentials-provider-dev.cpp` file:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_{package}_CredentialsProvider_extractApiCredentials(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    jclass cls = env -> FindClass("com/{path}/models/ApiCredentials");
    jmethodID methodId = env -> GetMethodID(cls, "<init>",
    "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    return env -> NewObject(cls, methodId,
                            env->NewStringUTF("key"),
                            env->NewStringUTF("other key"),
                            env->NewStringUTF("another key"),
                            env->NewStringUTF("key again"),
                            NULL, NULL
    );
}
```

My `build.gradle` defines the link to `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

My `src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(
    credentials-provider-dev
    SHARED
    credentials-provider-dev.cpp)
```

The `credentials-provider-dev` file only define my dev environment credentials and this code works fine when I build in Debug Type.

**Problem:**

I also have staging and release build and I want to use different `credentials-provider-{dev/staging/production}.cpp` file for each build type:

```
debug {
    ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
    applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
}

staging {
    initWith debug
    debuggable true
}

release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-app.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```

**Attempts:**

I use native code to store these keys because of better key protection. And I don't want to merge all the build keys into 1 file because of repo security. Only the person has the responsibility to access production build have the `credentials-provider-production.cpp` file and be able to build release. So my teammates can only have the `dev` file and build debug mode only.

I tried with `find_library` to check for staging `cpp` file existence before calling `add_library` like this but it didn't work, the lib is still not added:

```
find_file(
    STAGING_KEY_LIB
    PATHS main/cpp/credentials-provider-staging.cpp)
if (STAGING_KEY_LIB)
    add_library(
        credentials-provider-staging
        SHARED
        main/cpp/credentials-provider-staging.cpp)
endif()
```

I also tried the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` parameter sent to the `CMakeLists.txt` like below. But base on the [document](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake): `The valid values are Release and Debug`. I want to have Staging build too so this method didn't work

```
add_library(
    credentials-provider-${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    SHARED
    credentials-provider-${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}.cpp)
```

**In summary:**

Using native code: How can I separate my secret-key files into different build type-based files? Anyone has experience with this please help.
Thanks

Comment: why not using an environment variable?
Like BUILD_ENV, with the value of your environment like Dev, Prod and Stagging, then using this variable to select the appropriate file?

Comment: Hi, I cannot find a way to pass a custom variable to the CMake build process. The config in ``build.gradle` only defines the path to `CMakeLists.txt`. The parameters are automatically passed by Android and listed here (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake). The only parameter I found is `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` but cannot be used because it only support "Debug" or "Release"

Comment: I understand. You should be able to pass some var using environment.
you can then if defined, and access it with ENV{VAR_NAME}

I don't see a better way to do it, unless you compute BUILD_ENV directly in the CMake list

Comment: Thanks for the `$ENV` part, but this leads to a problem. I have to manually change the environment variable each time I change the build variant. I am still researching for a way to automate this process. Something like when changing the build variant will automatically set the env var and the code will use the correct file

Comment: Hum, I suggest to use an internal variable,
that is set to Dev when in Debug build
that is set to Staging when in Release
and when your CI, build the code, it should set the env var 
to prod

so you have

local_build_env=dev if debug

local_build_env=staging if release

local_build_env=ENV_build_env

then ENV_build_env is set to prod on your CI, or staging if you have a special build for it
otherwise it is set to dev.

Comment: Yes, it's what I want too. But currently, I cannot define a variable automatically base on build type. And even if I can, it cannot be passed to `CMakeLists` file by the way Android build my native code (at least base on what I've researched). If I only use env var and access it via $ENV in `CMakeList`, then every time I change the build type, I have to manually change the env var too. Which easily getting bug if I forgot to. This becomes more complex with too many constraints. I have a temporary solution for now and will post it soon. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: I don't really understand, why you can't declare a CMake variable and make use of it instead of CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE. 
As long as you can, catch the environment variable in CMake contexte, there is no need to pass another variable. (the build type at least if you want to use it) 
As last try I wrote a gist, that use an env variable and create the appropriate library with the appropriate credential file. 
https://gist.github.com/NokiDev/117c606950d275270e4d06ade10b68bf

https://gist.github.com/NokiDev/117c606950d275270e4d06ade10b68bf

Comment: But I'm looking forward seeing you answer I probably missed something

Comment: So you mean BUILD_ENV=dev in build Debug and BUILD_ENV=staging in build Release if BUILD_ENV is not defined. I don't think it works in my case, I want Debug => load dev file, Staging => staging file & Release => prod file. On my local machine, I am able to build all 3 types. So the solution possible is setting the BUILD_ENV directly from env var without using CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution:

**Project structure:**

```
src
| - CMakeLists.txt
|
| - debug/cpp
  | - CMakeLists.txt
  | - credentials-debug.cpp
|
| - main/cpp
  | - CMakeLists.txt
  | - credentials-release.cpp
|
| - staging/cpp
  | - CMakeLists.txt
  | - credentials-staging.cpp
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_subdirectory(debug/cpp)

add_subdirectory(staging/cpp)

add_subdirectory(main/cpp)
```

**src/debug/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
add_library(
    credentials-debug
    SHARED
    credentials-debug.cpp)
```

**src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:** (ignored in .gitignore & will be empty on other machine)

```
add_library(
    credentials-release
    SHARED
    credentials-release.cpp)
```

**src/staging/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:** (ignored in .gitignore & will be empty on other machine)

```
add_library(
    credentials-staging
    SHARED
    credentials-staging.cpp)
```

So each child `CMakeLists.txt` file loads a different cpp file.

- On my local machine, I'll have all 3 (CMakeLists + cpp) files.
- On other teammates that don't have permission to build staging or release. They don't have the staging + release cpp files and just a placeholder empty `CMakeList` files
- In the Kotlin code: I can extract the debug/staging/release build type to decide to load the right library

**Pros:**

- Change the build type is a 1 step process, just change the build variant from Android Studio and the code automatically pick the right native lib to import
- Important credentials files are ignored from repo

**Cons:**

- On my machine, all available cpp files for 3 build types are built from the beginning but only 1 of them is used
- When someone pulls the project, they have to manually create empty `CMakeLists` in main/cpp and staging/cpp folder so the `add_subdirectory` won't throw an error

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` which is passed by Android to CMake. In my case I wanted to use a specific library version, but this approach can also be used with an CMake `IF` to define a different flow.

```
string(TOLOWER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} BUILD_TYPE)
target_link_libraries(Bar  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Foo/lib/build/intermediates/library_and_local_jars_jni/${BUILD_TYPE}/jni/arm64-v8a/libFoo.so)
```